# Android Studio jPOS org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, jpos

I'm trying to use jpos in my android project, I downloaded a fields.xml from an example from the internet. I would like to know why or how I resolve this error when calling the GenericPackager function.

`java.lang.Exception: org.jpos.iso.ISOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Activity-DQzzXo3E8QpU-bmLtFYx-Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Activity-DQzzXo3E8QpU-bmLtFYx-Q==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]`

```
package com.Activity.ISO;

import android.util.Log;

import com.Activity.Others.App;

import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

public class PackISOMessage {


    public String buildISOMessage() throws Exception {

        try {
            // Load package from resources directory.
            //InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("fields.xml");

            InputStream xmlDoc = App.getContext().getAssets().open("fields.xml");

            //String file = "/fields.xml";
            GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(xmlDoc); //Here is debug error

            ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
            isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
            isoMsg.setMTI("0200");

            isoMsg.set(3, "000010");
            isoMsg.set(4, "1500");
            isoMsg.set(7, "1206041200");
            isoMsg.set(11, "000001");
            isoMsg.set(41, "12340001");
            isoMsg.set(49, "840");
            printISOMessage(isoMsg);

            byte[] result = isoMsg.pack();
            return new String(result);
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

    private void printISOMessage(ISOMsg isoMsg) {

        try {
            System.out.printf("MTI = %s%n", isoMsg.getMTI());
            for (int i = 1; i <= isoMsg.getMaxField(); i++) {
                if (isoMsg.hasField(i)) {
                    System.out.printf("Field (%s) = %s%n", i, isoMsg.getString(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

And this is my fields.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN" "jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd" >

<isopackager>
  <isofield id="0" length="4" name="MESSAGE TYPE INDICATOR" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="1" length="16" name="BIT MAP" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BITMAP"/>
  <isofield id="2" length="19" name="SECRET ID" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="3" length="6" name="PROCESSING CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="4" length="12" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="5" length="12" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="6" length="12" name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="7" length="10" name="TRANSMISSION DATE AND TIME" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="8" length="8" name="AMOUNT, CARDHOLDER BILLING FEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="9" length="8" name="CONVERSION RATE, SETTLEMENT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="10" length="8" name="CONVERSION RATE, CARDHOLDER BILLING" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="11" length="6" name="SYSTEM TRACE AUDIT NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="12" length="6" name="TIME, LOCAL TRANSACTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="13" length="4" name="DATE, LOCAL TRANSACTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="14" length="4" name="DATE, EXPIRATION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="15" length="4" name="DATE, SETTLEMENT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="16" length="4" name="DATE, CONVERSION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="17" length="4" name="DATE, CAPTURE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="18" length="4" name="MERCHANTS TYPE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="19" length="3" name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="20" length="3" name="PAN EXTENDED COUNTRY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="21" length="3" name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="22" length="3" name="POINT OF SERVICE ENTRY MODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="23" length="3" name="CARD SEQUENCE NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="24" length="3" name="NETWORK INTERNATIONAL IDENTIFIEER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="25" length="2" name="POINT OF SERVICE CONDITION CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="26" length="2" name="POINT OF SERVICE PIN CAPTURE CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="27" length="1" name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESP LEN" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="28" length="9" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION FEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield id="29" length="9" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT FEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield id="30" length="9" name="AMOUNT, TRANSACTION PROCESSING FEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield id="31" length="9" name="AMOUNT, SETTLEMENT PROCESSING FEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield id="32" length="11" name="ACQUIRING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="33" length="11" name="FORWARDING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="34" length="28" name="PAN EXTENDED" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="35" length="37" name="TRACK 2 DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="36" length="104" name="TRACK 3 DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="37" length="12" name="RETRIEVAL REFERENCE NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="38" length="6" name="AUTHORIZATION IDENTIFICATION RESPONSE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="39" length="2" name="RESPONSE CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="40" length="3" name="SERVICE RESTRICTION CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="41" length="8" name="CARD ACCEPTOR TERMINAL IDENTIFICACION" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="42" length="15" name="CARD ACCEPTOR IDENTIFICATION CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="43" length="40" name="CARD ACCEPTOR NAME/LOCATION" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="44" length="25" name="ADITIONAL RESPONSE DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="45" length="76" name="TRACK 1 DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="46" length="999" name="ADITIONAL DATA - ISO" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="47" length="999" name="ADITIONAL DATA - NATIONAL" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="48" length="999" name="ADITIONAL DATA - PRIVATE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="49" length="3" name="CURRENCY CODE, TRANSACTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="50" length="3" name="CURRENCY CODE, SETTLEMENT" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="51" length="3" name="CURRENCY CODE, CARDHOLDER BILLING" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="52" length="16" name="PIN DATA" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="53" length="16" name="SECURITY RELATED CONTROL INFORMATION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="54" length="120" name="ADDITIONAL AMOUNTS" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="55" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="56" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="57" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="58" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="59" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="60" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="61" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="62" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="63" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="64" length="8" name="MESSAGE AUTHENTICATION CODE FIELD" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield id="65" length="1" name="BITMAP, EXTENDED" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield id="66" length="1" name="SETTLEMENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="67" length="2" name="EXTENDED PAYMENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="68" length="3" name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="69" length="3" name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION COUNTRY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="70" length="3" name="NETWORK MANAGEMENT INFORMATION CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="71" length="4" name="MESSAGE NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="72" length="4" name="MESSAGE NUMBER LAST" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="73" length="6" name="DATE ACTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="74" length="10" name="CREDITS NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="75" length="10" name="CREDITS REVERSAL NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="76" length="10" name="DEBITS NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="77" length="10" name="DEBITS REVERSAL NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="78" length="10" name="TRANSFER NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="79" length="10" name="TRANSFER REVERSAL NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="80" length="10" name="INQUIRIES NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="81" length="10" name="AUTHORIZATION NUMBER" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="82" length="12" name="CREDITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="83" length="12" name="CREDITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="84" length="12" name="DEBITS, PROCESSING FEE AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="85" length="12" name="DEBITS, TRANSACTION FEE AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="86" length="16" name="CREDITS, AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="87" length="16" name="CREDITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="88" length="16" name="DEBITS, AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="89" length="16" name="DEBITS, REVERSAL AMOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="90" length="42" name="ORIGINAL DATA ELEMENTS" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
  <isofield id="91" length="1" name="FILE UPDATE CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="92" length="2" name="FILE SECURITY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="93" length="6" name="RESPONSE INDICATOR" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="94" length="7" name="SERVICE INDICATOR" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="95" length="42" name="REPLACEMENT AMOUNTS" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="96" length="16" name="MESSAGE SECURITY CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
  <isofield id="97" length="17" name="AMOUNT, NET SETTLEMENT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_AMOUNT"/>
  <isofield id="98" length="25" name="PAYEE" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
  <isofield id="99" length="11" name="SETTLEMENT INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="100" length="11" name="RECEIVING INSTITUTION IDENT CODE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLNUM"/>
  <isofield id="101" length="17" name="FILE NAME" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="102" length="28" name="FROM ACCOUNT" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="103" length="10" name="ACCOUNT IDENTIFICATION 2" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="104" length="100" name="TRANSACTION DESCRIPTION" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="105" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="106" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="107" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="108" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="109" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="110" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="111" length="999" name="RESERVED ISO USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="112" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="113" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="114" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="115" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="116" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="117" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="118" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="119" length="999" name="RESERVED NATIONAL USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="120" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="121" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="122" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="123" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="124" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="125" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="126" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="127" length="999" name="RESERVED PRIVATE USE" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_LLLCHAR"/>
  <isofield id="128" length="8" name="MAC 2" class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_BINARY"/>
</isopackager>
```

My pack button config:

```
ButtonPack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackISOMessage iso = new PackISOMessage();
                try {
                    String message = iso.buildISOMessage();
                    System.out.printf("Message = %s", message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Sorry for anything, i'm new to programming.

Comment: See if this helps. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser--mobile-9041. 
For one thing XMLReaderImpl from apache crimson is no more maintained. Using this is discouraged and can lead to lot of issues. 
If your objective is to parse XML data. Then try https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

Comment: It seems you don't have the required dependency that provides  org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl class needed by GenericPackager  to parse the packager definition fields.xml

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz And how i get this?

Comment: sorry is not a dependency, you need to provide an `XMLReader` implementation class available in your classpath by passing this system property, I don't know much about android development, so I don't know how you set system properties in an android project, but you need to provide the fully qualified name of such a class in the property `org.xml.sax.driver` by default `GenericPackager` tries to use `org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl` if the system doesn't provide a default one, which is what's giving you the exception,

Comment: Maybe one of these two dependencies solves your problem https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/crimson/crimson/1.1.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.0

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same error by adding the following code before instantiating the packager:

```
System.setProperty("org.xml.sax.driver", "org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver");
Field versionShown = org.jpos.util.Logger.class.getDeclaredField("versionShown");
versionShown.setAccessible(true);
versionShown.set(null, true);
```

Then, you can instantiate the packager:

```
GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager(xmlDoc);
```